# webscraping a table with no html class

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I exploring webscraping some weather data, specifically the table on the right panel of this page https://wrcc.dri.edu/cgi-bin/cliMAIN.pl?ak4988

I'm able to navigate to the appropriate location (see below), but have not been able to pull out the table e.g., `html_nodes("table")`.

```
  library(tidyverse)
  library(rvest)


  url<- read_html("https://wrcc.dri.edu/cgi-bin/cliMAIN.pl?ak4988") 

  url %>% 
   html_nodes("frame") %>% 
   magrittr::extract2(2)

  # {html_node}
  # <frame src="/cgi-bin/cliRECtM.pl?ak4988" name="Graph">
```

I've also looked at the namespace with no luck

```
xml_ns(url)

# <->
```

Comment: I'm not super familiar with R or rvest, but it may be an issue with the table being inside a frame. Try scraping the frame's source page: https://wrcc.dri.edu/cgi-bin/cliRECtM.pl?ak4988. If you need to get that URL programmatically, you can find it by extracting the "src" attribute from the <frame> element.

Comment: `html_nodes("iframe")` yields `{xml_nodeset (0)}` doesn't seem to get me to the proper location, though maybe I'm just misunderstanding?

Comment: Yeah sorry, it's a frame not an iframe, I edited my comment. But try scraping the frame's page, and do `html_nodes("table")` on that page.

Comment: So you're url line should be `url<- read_html("https://wrcc.dri.edu/cgi-bin/cliRECtM.pl?ak4988")` (which is the url that the `frame` loads)

Comment: Ahhh I see that the link I sent shows a different table than the one I'm looking at (though the url is the same). In the left side nav pane scroll down to Temperature>Monthly Temperature Listings>Average. Any idea on how to navigate to that, seems like the source page is mis-directed?

Comment: Yeah, if you right click the link that you want and choose "open link in new tab" then it should open a new tab with the proper URL. You could also extract the link from the `<a>` element by reading the value of the `href` attribute.

Comment: perfect, thanks for helping me as I stumble through learning html.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
library(rvest)
library(magrittr)
library(plyr)

#Doing URLs one by one
url<-"https://wrcc.dri.edu/cgi-bin/cliRECtM.pl?ak4988"

##GET SALES DATA
pricesdata <- read_html(url) %>% html_nodes(xpath = "//table[1]") %>% html_table(fill=TRUE)
library(plyr)
df <- ldply(pricesdata, data.frame)
```

Originally I was hitting the wrong URL.  The comment from Mogzol pointed me in the right direction.  I'm not sure how, or why, different URLs feed into the same one. Maybe it has something to do with the different scrolling windows in one single window.  I would be interested in hearing how this works...if someone has some insight into it...  Thanks!!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/frame

Comment: Oh, I see.  Thanks.